# Call vbs from VBScript

Tags: vbscript, call, wsh

I am trying to do a simple function that will call one VBScript file and run that simultaneously to the script that is currently running.  I have searched online and I discovered a technique using WScript.Shell object, however since my company switched to Windows 7, it doesn't seem to work the way it did in Windows XP.  I'm hoping this is some stupid issue with my code, but it keeps giving me the error:

> Script_Call_tester.vbs(5, 2) (null): The system cannot find the file specified.

I did export the file path and name for the script I am trying to call, and when I paste it into the run prompt, it does find the script.

```
sendExports("Script_Called_tester.vbs")
function sendExports(iScript)
    dim objShell
    set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    objShell.Run "\\path\" & iScript
    set objShell = Nothing
    wscript.echo("call worked")
    wscript.sleep(3000)
end function
```

Comment: _The system cannot find the file specified_. Which file? The script or the host executable? Try `objShell.Run """" & "\\path\" & iScript & """"` or `objShell.Run WScript.FullName & " \\path\" & iScript` or a combination...

Comment: The most likely explanation is that your obfuscated path `\\path\Script_Called_tester.vbs` contains a space somewhere. The first sample from @JosefZ's comment should take care of that. Not much else we could tell you without more information.

Comment: Another possibility that, by a mistake, the `\\path` refers to non-existing  _host name of a server or the domain name of a domain hosting resource_ named `path`; not much else we could tell you without more information about real invocation of that `path` string and it's meaning

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is anything to do with Windows 7.

`Script_Called_tester.vbs` Copy this file from the network location and place it in your local machine. Update the path in the script to your local. Run it.  Does it work fine? (It should)

What happens when you try to access this **`\path\Script_Called_tester.vbs`** directly in the 'Windows search Programs and files".

Are you able to find?